# quickfix window under vim with syntastic

Tags: vim, go, syntastic

I have the following [vimrc](https://github.com/mictadlo/vimrc4GO/blob/master/.vimrc) for go. If I press :w I will get

[image]

and than I do :make

```
$ vim closure.go 

make: *** No targets specified and no makefile found.  Stop.

Press ENTER or type command to continue
[No write since last change]
# _/home/x
./closure.go:27: undefined: fmt.P
./maps.go:5: main redeclared in this block
    previous declaration at ./closure.go:23
./slices.go:5: main redeclared in this block
    previous declaration at ./maps.go:5

Press ENTER or type command to continue
```

After pressing ENTER Vim looks like that [image]

Unfortunately, I do not the following output [image]

What did I do wrong?

Comment: Can you do `:h syntastic`?

Comment: Syntastic is not triggered by `:make` but by `:w`. If Syntastic doesn't check your syntax on `:w` it's probably badly configured/installed.

Comment: Before I added "autocmd QuickFixCmdPost [^l]* nested cwindow" and "autocmd QuickFixCmdPost    l* nested lwindow" to my vimrc, I have got the red error arrows by using :w, but not a  QuickFix window.

Comment: What is the output of `let g:syntastic_auto_loc_list`?

Comment: g:syntastic_auto_loc_list #2

Comment: Try `let g:syntastic_auto_loc_list = 1`.

Comment: Now :w check the synatax http://i.imgur.com/ZMTQUNd.png, but it also check other files and it does not show red and yellow arrows.

Comment: The error list generated by syntastic after `:w` looks exactly like the error list generated by `:make` so we are on the right track, I'd say. Did you actually read `:h syntastic` and play with the options?

Comment: Unfortunately not, because I thought it would work out of the box.

Comment: Thank you for the tipps and here is how I did it https://github.com/mictadlo/vimrc4GO/blob/master/.vimrc

Answer (score 0):

Apparently Syntastic uses the location-list (`:lwindow`) and not the quickfix (`:cwindow`).